# ORDER BY BASED ON COLUMN

Tags: sorting, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, columnsorting

I have two tables,PRODUCTS AND LOOKUP TABLES.Now i want to order the KEY Column in products table based on KEY column value in LOOKUP TABLE.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
    ID INT,
    KEY VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS 
VALUES (1, 'EGHS'), (2, 'PFE'), (3, 'EGHS'),
       (4, 'PFE'), (5, 'ABC')

CREATE TABLE LOOKUP (F_KEY VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO LOOKUP VALUES('PFE,EGHS,ABC')
```

Now I want to order the records in PRODUCTS table based on KEY (`PFE,EGHS,ABC`) values in LOOKUP table.

Example output:

PRODUCTS

```
ID   F_KEY
-----------    
2    PFE
4    PFE
1    EGHS
3    EGHS
5    ABC
```

I use this query, but it is not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCTS 
ORDER BY (SELECT F_KEY FROM LOOKUP)
```

Comment: What if `FKEY` had values like 'PFE,ABC, EGHS' then what would the result be? What I am trying to clarify is do you want to order by the values in `FKEY` or would those values dictate the order based on the order they appear. Can you also indicate why do you want to do this because I have never come across such a problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string using `XML`. You first need to convert the string to `XML` and replace the comma with start and end `XML` tags.

Once done, you can assign an incrementing number using `ROW_NUMBER()` like following.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT dt, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN 
         FROM   (SELECT Cast('<X>' + Replace(F.f_key, ',', '</X><X>') 
                             + '</X>' AS XML) AS xmlfilter 
                 FROM   [lookup] F)F1 
                CROSS apply (SELECT fdata.d.value('.', 'varchar(500)') AS DT 
                             FROM   f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(d)) O) 
SELECT P.* 
FROM   products P 
       LEFT JOIN cte C 
              ON C.dt = P.[key] 
ORDER  BY C.rn
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/CPIE28045)

**Output:**

```
ID   F_KEY
-----------    
2    PFE
4    PFE
1    EGHS
3    EGHS
5    ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like this:

```
SELECT ID, [KEY] FROM PRODUCTS
ORDER BY
CASE [KEY]
  WHEN 'PFE' THEN 1
  WHEN 'EGHS' THEN 2
  WHEN 'ABC' THEN 3
END
```

Comment: Above query is fine.But KEY is hard coded in above query.Suppose if the KEY value is changed (or) increased in LOOKUP Table.We need to change above query also For example(PFE,EGHS,ABC,JKR),.so Is there any dynamic query to do this?